# Duplicate Checking vs Creating a set typescript

Tags: typescript, performance, duplicates

Somewhat of a basic question, while iterating through a array of objects, I need to build up a list of unique strings, would adding an if statement in a loop be better than creating a set ?

`if (!arr.includes(newString)) arr.push(newString)`

VS
push all strings and then

`arr = [ ...new Set(arr) ]`

Comment: Better in what sense?

Comment: Performance (which one uses more memory / more processing) when working with big lists, I know traditionally adding if statements is considered bad due to how Typescript is compiled down all the way BUT I have no idea of how Set works in the background (I will go do some research on this in the meanwhile)

Comment: Memory and runtime performance are different metrics. Also such metrics depend on the environment (eg the JS engine). If this truly is your question, you need to be much more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Set` is much, *much* faster.

Let's do a test on [jsbench.me](https://jsbench.me/h9kv91l8np/1)

### Setup:

Let's create an array with numbers 0-9999, and then 0-9999 again for 20,000 items, each of which has exactly one duplicate.

```
const data = []
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) data.push(i)
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) data.push(i)
```

### Loop Test:

```
let arr = []
for (let n of data) {
  if (!arr.includes(n)) arr.push(n) 
}
```

9.72 executions per second

### Set test:

```
let arr = [ ...new Set(data) ]
```

1422.54 executions per second

---

[Run the test yourself here](https://jsbench.me/h9kv91l8np/1)

So the `Set` is ***146 times faster*** (on my machine)

I suspect it's because `Set` is implemented with native compiled code, which simple cannot be beat for performance and efficiency when done properly. And you can trust that the browsers implementations of builtins are probably very very good.

Also pretty much anything you can do to avoid loops over large arrays is a good thing for performance.

Comment: Everything is at some point implemented with compiled code =) The difference is the underlying data structure and time-complexity required to find items. It's possible to do something very fast in pure JS as well, if a hash is used.

Comment: Easiest version would be to use an object, and store the items as keys.

Comment: I did a version of this, and it _is_ slower though (but not as much): `const arr = Array.from(
  Object.keys(
    Object.fromEntries(
      data.map(item => [item, true])
    )
  )
);`